# Overlapping records between two dates using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, date

In my application a user can delegate another user to approve orders.

What I need to validate, is that there are no circular references so if `User A` is has delegated `User B` over a certain period, `User B` can not delegate `User A` for any time within that period, i.e there is an overlap (dates in `dd/mm/yyyy`):

```
Delegator    Delegated To    DateFrom    DateTo
User A       User B          01/11/2012  08/11/2012
User A       User B          16/12/2012  24/12/2012
```

This is the code I have to check for overlaps:

```
var overlaps = .Session.QueryOver<DelegateOrderApproval>()
    .Where(x => x.DateFrom > DateTime.Now && delegateOrderApproval.DelegatedUser.UserId == x.DelegatorUser.UserId)
    .And(x => x.DateFrom >= delegateOrderApproval.DateFrom && delegateOrderApproval.DateTo <= x.DateTo
              || (x.DateFrom >= delegateOrderApproval.DateFrom && x.DateTo <= delegateOrderApproval.DateTo)
              || (x.DateFrom <= delegateOrderApproval.DateFrom && x.DateTo >= delegateOrderApproval.DateFrom)
              || (x.DateFrom <= delegateOrderApproval.DateFrom && x.DateTo >= delegateOrderApproval.DateTo))
    .List();
```

If I try to add the following record:

```
Delegator: User B
Delegated  To: User A
Date From: 15/11/2012
DateTo:    21/11/2012
```

there should be no conflict as `User B` is not a delegate for `User A` in that time period? It's picking up the record in December.

I have searched for date range overlapping code and tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you are using QueryOver from NHibernate, should your check run at the database level? If yes, I think you should tag the question with some NHibernate-related tag because that might impact the way you could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply do

```
var doesOverlapExist = Session.QueryOver<DelegateOrderApproval>()
     .Any(x => 
        x.DateFrom > DateTime.Now && 
        delegateOrderApproval.DelegatedUser.UserId == x.DelegatorUser.UserId &&
        x.DateFrom <= delegateOrderApproval.DateTo &&
        x.DateTo >= delegateOrderApproval.DateFrom);
```

or if you don't have any, replace with

```
Where(x=> blabla).Count() >0
```

overlap check logic :
[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: Yep, that did it. Think I was over complicating it!! Thanks a lot Raphaël!